# Finding out where and why Newtonsoft fails parsing string

Tags: .net-core, base64, postman

Hello i am facing with the following problem :
I am trying to send through `Postman` a `Base64` encoded image.The server throws the following exception when trying to `ReadBodyAsync` the request:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'data.extraDeps', line 19, position 667.
```

I have tried sending another string and it passes.So the problem is with this specific string which unfortunately i have to find out where and why it breaks.
Postman however does not show the `columns` when you click inside the `body` of the request so i would have to manually count the characters until reaching `667`. Is there any sound approach to this ?

Comment: Have you checked the JSON is valid using an online service such as https://jsonlint.com/?

Comment: The json image is valid , i have tried decompressing it and it works.Also the request works without this image string.I have tried with other strings and it works.